# Getting 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro for a hydro-logic model worth a decent % of my grade, and I keep getting the `1004` error. It's centered on the first line of the first If statement.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
Sub pheonix()
'
' pheonix Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+u
'
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = Sheets.Add
    Sheets.Add.Name = "RESULTS"
    Sheets("Case 2").Select

    Range("C1:R1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("RESULTS").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste


    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Day As Integer
    Dim SurfaceInflow As Integer
    Dim GroundwaterOutflow As Integer
    Dim SurfaceOutflow As Integer
    Dim Stage As Integer
    Dim Evap As Integer
    Dim Precip As Integer
    Dim AreaL As Integer
    Dim ChangeStorage As Integer
    Dim Storage As Integer

    Dim InitialStorage As Integer
    Dim InitialStage As Integer
    Dim InitialArea As Integer



    Row = 2

    'calulation for initial day
    'InitialStage = "4"
    'InitialArea = 11 * InitialStage ^ 0.5
    'InitialStorage = (22 / 3) * (InitialStage ^ (3 / 2))

    Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Case 2")
    Set wksDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RESULTS")

     For Day = 5 To 734
        Sheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, "A") = Sheets("Case 2").Cells(Row, "C")


        For i = 0 To 288
             Sheets("Case 2").Select

                SurfaceInflow = ((0.2 * Cells(Day, "G")) * ((1 - 0.4) * (557 - Cells(Day, "J")))) + ((0.95 * Cells(Day, "G")) * (0.4 * (557 - Cells(Day, "J"))))

                If Cells(Stage, "H") >= 1.348 Then
                    GroundwaterOutflow = (0.379 * Cells(Stage, "H") - 0.511)
                    Else: GroundwaterOutflow = 0
                End If

                If Cells(Stage, "H") > 2.9 Then
                    SurfaceInflow = (33 * (Cells(Stage, "H") - 2.9) ^ (3 / 2))
                    Else: SurfaceInflow = 0
                End If

                Precip = Cells(Precip, "S")

                Evap = Cells(Evap, "T")

                Area = (11 * Cells(Stage, "H") ^ 0.5)

                ChangeStorage = (Area * (Precip - Evap)) - GroundwaterOutflow + SurfaceInflow - SurfaceOutflow

                Storage = Storage + ChangeStorage


        Next i
            Sheets("RESULTS").Cells(Row, "B") = "X"
            Row = Row + 1

     Next Day

End Sub
```

Help? I'm not super familiar with any programming, this was a rather unfortunate project sprung on us by the prof.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the value of `Stage` is `0` in

```
If Cells(Stage, "H") >= 1.348 Then
```

Excel rows start with `1` and can go up to a max of `65536` in xl2003 and previous or to `1048576` in xl2007+

Also it is advisable to declare the row variable(s) as `Long` instead of `Integer`

You might also want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) to make your code more robust.

Comment: But why would it be 0 there? Am I not selecting columns to work with?

Comment: You have to set a value of `stage` as it is as variable. If you step through the code using F8, you will notice that the value of `stage` is `0`. Or you can simply type this before that `IF` line. `MSGBOX Stage`

Comment: ahhhh, now I see. I somehow missed an equation in there. Thanks!!

Comment: @user3000426, since this answered your question, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. That way future readers will know it's the answer (and Siddharth will have even more points :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work